# How to work with optional parameters that are set to None

Tags: python, optional-parameters

With named parameters, how can I tell the receiver method to use the "not supplied" version of the parameter?  Sending in None does not work.  The following is my specific code, note especially the following portion:

```
args=launch[1:] if launch[4] is not None else None
```

I would like if possible to keep the list comprehensions

```
procs = [Process(name=key, target=launch[0],
               args=launch[1:] if launch[4] is not None else None)
       for key, launch in zip(procinfos.keys(), launches)]
```

The result is the one-args version of process is selected, and then complains the args is None:

```
File "<stdin>", line 15, in parallel
          for key, launch in zip(procinfos.keys(), launches)]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 104, in __init__
 self._args = tuple(args)
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

There is of course a brute-force method:  that is to duplicate part of the for-comprehension and simply refrain from specifying the args= parameter.  I will probably end up going that route .. unless an alternative magically appears here ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to specify the named arguments as a dictionary, with `args` not being present if `launch[4] is None`, e.g.:

```
procs = []
for key, launch in zip(procinfos.keys(), launches):
     params = {"name": key, "target": launch[0]}
     if launch[4] is not None:
         params["args"] = launch[1:]
     procs.append(Process(**params))
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `args` is an empty tuple, not `None`:

```
launch[1:] if launch[4] is not None else ()
```

I would really avoid writing three-line one-liners. There's nothing wrong with regular `for` loops:

```
processes = []

for key, launch in zip(procinfos, launches):
    args = launch[1:] if launch[4] is not None else ()
    process = Process(name=key, target=launch[0], args=args)

    processes.append(process)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `None` with an empty Tuple: `()`

```
procs = [Process(name=key, target=launch[0],
           args=launch[1:] if launch[4] is not None else ())
   for key, launch in zip(procinfos.keys(), launches)]
```

Comment: also helpful, thanks. I would give credit for both of these answers so far, but .. rules ..